# Young Adult series/trilogy about nefarious plot to transfer memories from rich people with disabled/dying bodies to young donor bodies

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

Young adult trilogy about a group of kids/teens go on various adventures to take down a secret program that wipes memories of donor bodies and replaces them with the memories/consciousness of rich people with dying/disabled bodies.

Additional info:

- Some of the characters:

  - West, a semi-cyborg who works security for the bad guys
  - Shade, one of the protagonists, sister of one of the other protagonists
- There's quite a bit about these electrodes implanted in the heads of some of the participants of the program
- Here's one scene I remember quite well: the protagonists find a rich senator who is partaking in the program, and they capture video of her head with a bunch of "terminals" for wires to go into. She ends up visiting the doctor in charge of the program and he removes the terminals. Then, at a press meet, someone demands she takes off her wig, and she does, "revealing" that she has cancer, discrediting the teens.
- Another thing I remember: the first book in the series starts with a group of animal activists who break into a biotech company's lab and rescue mice and a cyborg dog

I've scoured Google and Google books, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you recall any of the details of the covers?

Comment: I read this book a few years ago. I don't remember any details of the cover.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the book. It's called *[Uncaged](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/18800159-uncaged)* by John Sandford and Michele Cook. It's part of a series called '[The Singular Menace](https://www.goodreads.com/series/116363-the-singular-menace).'

> Shay Remby arrives in Hollywood with $58 and a handmade knife, searching for her brother, Odin.
>
> Odin’s a brilliant hacker but a bit of a loose cannon. He and a group of radical animal-rights activists hit a Singular Corp. research lab in Eugene, Oregon. The raid was a disaster, but Odin escaped with a set of highly encrypted flash drives and a post-surgical dog.
>
> When Shay gets a frantic 3 a.m. phone call from Odin—talking about evidence of unspeakable experiments, and a ruthless corporation, and how he must hide—she’s concerned. When she gets a menacing visit from Singular’s security team, she knows: her brother’s a dead man walking.
>
> What Singular doesn’t know—yet—is that 16-year-old Shay is every bit as ruthless as their security force, and she will burn Singular to the ground, if that’s what it takes to save her brother.